# iphone changing the initial scene

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In my iphone application I have two scenes, both of them are view controllers.
Normally initial scene is set to the first one. When user plays it passes to the second one.

At this point when the user closes the app and restarts it, if the user has already played, it should start with the second scene, so the initial scene should change for that user.

How can I do this?

And i dont use a navigation controller.

Comment: Please post some of the code for your application. The answer for this question depends heavily on how your application is structured.

Comment: You can think it as i dont have any code but two scene with initial set to the first one. But i want to change it to the second one with code..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using xibs, you set this up in the app delegates 
`applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Create a global BOOL and check it's value on applications launch, E.g:

.h

```
@class ViewController;
@class SecondViewController;
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SecondViewController *SecondViewController;
```

.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if (isSecondViewControllerBool == YES) {
        self.SecondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    }else{
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

For storyboards:

In the first view controllers `viewDidLoad`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    if (isSecondViewControllerBool == YES) {
        UIViewController *secondVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mySecondViewController"];
        [self presentViewController:secondVC animated:NO completion:nil];

    }else{
        //present normally
    }
}
```

If you are using storyboards and have decided to use my xib solution, delete the storyboard from the project, and remove it here as well:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info, i use storyboard but i dont want to change the initial scene by hand, i want it to be changed automatically by code in some cases..

Comment: Thanks! should i modify anything in this line  self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc]... as it says unknown reciever viewController?

Comment: @user446141 I've added the code to fix that, sorry about that!

Comment: @JTApps Thanks for the vote! Too bad we can only hope for answer approvals!

Comment: No errors but getting the following runtime error..Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

Comment: Did you remove the storyboard from the target?

Comment: Do you mean removing the storyboard from the project? Sorry i am a beginner. But thank you for your help!

Comment: @user446141 Yes, I've made another edit to show you what else to do, and no problem! Now, the method you have chosen will only work if you are using xibs instead of storyboards.

Comment: Much appreciated.. Isnt there any way to do this with keeping the storyboard?

Comment: @user446141 there's the viewDidLoad option that I specified above, but that isn't really a good method, and it's the only way I know of that it can be done with storyboard. Basically what it does is load view controller 1, then before it actually appears on screen I loads up 2 on top of it.